# Format string in to Date Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to convert

```
Thu Jan 22 07:10:00 CST 2015
```

into date format of `mm/dd/yyyy` => 01/22/2015.

I tried using the `convert` function with `datetime` and format types:

```
select convert(varchar(11, 'Thu Jan 22 07:10:00 CST 2015', 109)
```

but I get an error.

Comment: reason for down vote?

Comment: If u had the type already as date then only it will work. I suppose the dat u mentioned is in date and not in varchar

Comment: When some one seeks for help, can be commented to fix it rather down voting.Sharing knowledge is not a harm anytime.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting? We can't read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us!**

Answer (score 0):

Is the error because you are missing a bracket?

```
select convert(varchar(11), 'Thu Jan 22 07:10:00 CST 2015', 109)
                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

i had it solved by following sql. posting here so it will help someone in need

```
select convert(varchar(11),convert(datetime,Right('Thu Jan 22 07:10:00 CST 2015',4) +'-'+ SUBSTRING('Thu Jan 22 07:10:00 CST 2015',5,3)+'-'+substring('Thu Jan 22 07:10:00 CST 2015',9,2)),101) DateValue
```